# What is the right way to use HttpClientConnectionManager with CloseableHttpClient in Apache?

Tags: java, httpclient, apache-httpcomponents

#### Context

I have an instance of `org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient`
and a singleton instance of `org.apache.hc.client5.http.io.HttpClientConnectionManager` to communicate with some remote API.

I have created a singleton pool of HTTP connections to create an instance of the HTTP client.

#### What is the right way to use HttpClientConnectionManager?

Should I really use try-with-resource (or old-style try-finally) to work with CloseableHttpClient?

If I close the HTTP client, a connection will be closed also from this pool. And then I can't use this pool to communicate with a remote API.

Of course, I've read the documentation https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html

Maybe something I missed. Could anyone explain me?

Answer (score 1):

You should also be using `CloseableHttpClient` as a singleton (on a per distinct service basis).

If you want to continue creating short lived instances of `CloseableHttpClient` with the same `HttpClientConnectionManager` please make sure to mark it as shared when creating `CloseableHttpClient` instances with `HttpClientBuilder`.

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean "to mark as shared"? Could you explain, please?

Comment: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder.html#setConnectionManagerShared(boolean)